# condition is True if pandas rows found more than one and drop latest

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, amazon-ec2

I have written a pandas dataframe to find instances where 'instanceList' has all the instance details stored.

```
instanceList = [
    [
        "web-mgmt",
        "i-0268214908adb3949",
        "running",
        "2019-05-06 13:30:11+00:00"
    ],
    [
        "app-srv-1",
        "i-088d90fe72g67fb4c",
        "running",
        "2019-06-04 03:46:03+00:00"
    ],
    [
        "web-mgmt",
        "i-0cwewrgbr45fc8823",
        "running",
        "2019-05-22 14:45:32+00:00"
    ]
]
```

```
df = pd.DataFrame(instanceList, columns=['InstanceName', 'InstanceId', 'InstanceState', 'LaunchTime'])
df['Dates'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LaunchTime']).dt.date
df['Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['LaunchTime']).dt.time
del df['LaunchTime']
```

Output to this filter is:

```
   InstanceName           InstanceId InstanceState       Dates      Time
2      web-mgmt  i-0268214908adb3949       running  2019-04-19  14:25:11
3      app-srv-1 i-088d90fe72g67fb4c       running  2019-06-04  03:46:03
5      web-mgmt  i-0cwewrgbr45fc8823       running  2019-05-06  10:30:10
```

Now i want to have below requirement fulfilled:

a. Find duplicates based on name tag. If no duplicates, print message.

b. If duplicate found, remove the latest instance by looking into date, so i can get all the older instances in the list.

So far i am able to find duplicate instances with below

```
# Find duplicate instance based on tag name
duplicateRows = df[df.duplicated(['InstanceName'], keep=False)]
print(duplicateRows, sep='\n')
```

that output below table.

```
   InstanceName           InstanceId InstanceState       Dates      Time
2      web-mgmt  i-0268214908adb3949       running  2019-04-19  14:25:11
5      web-mgmt  i-0cwewrgbr45fc8823       running  2019-05-06  10:30:10
```

Is there any way to put statement with condition like this? not able to figureout, please help me.

```
if df<SOMETHING> >= 1
  duplicateRows = df[df.duplicated(['InstanceName'], keep=False)]
  latest = duplicateRows.max()
  older = duplicateRows.drop(latest) <<-- error: datetime.time(14, 25, 11)] not found in axis
  print(older)
else:
  print message
```

Comment: I have the instanceList updated. Please let me know if this is clear to understand.

Answer (score 1):

Then convert instance name into a unique only list:

```
l = list(set(df['InstanceName'].tolist()))
```

Use the list to filter the df, drop the required:

```
x = []
for i in l:
    df_i = df.loc[df['InstanceName']==i]
    if len(df_i) > 1:
       df_i.set_index('Dates',drop=True,inplace=True)
       df_i = df_i.tail(len(df_i) - 1)
    df_i.reset_index(inplace=True)
    x.append(df_i)

df_final = pd.concat(x,ignore_index=True)

for i,row in df_final.iterrows():
    print(row)
```

Comment: I want to drop the latest one by date to get all older instances only. @Sid

Comment: @Rio check now.

Comment: With `duplicateRows = df[df.duplicated(['InstanceName'], keep=False)]` i am able to find duplicates. duplicates can be any number over a period of time. My goal is to remove the latest one of the list actually. @Sid

Comment: @Rio So if same instance has three different dates you would like to keep 2 of the dates and remove the latest?

Comment: Yes. Correct. So later I can clean those instances based on the report.

Comment: @Rio See now, you might want the `head` where I have given `tail` if the results are opposite of what you need.